# Do I need to install Koalas on every node of my Spark cluster or just on the master node?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, spark-koalas

I discovered [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas) from Spark+AI Summit which brings pandas to Spark.

As far as I know if I need to `map` a third party function to a Spark `DataFrame`, I have to install the package on every node of my Spark cluster.

Is this the same for Koalas? Or I just need to run `pip install koalas` on my master node and let Koalas and Spark to take care of the rest?

I haven't found any details in Koalas' [Docs](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html) besides the `pip install koalas`.

Comment: I was also looking for something along this line. My impression was that I can install koalas on my local machine and tell it where the cluster is. It didn't occur to me that it has to be installed on the cluster at all...

Answer (score -1):

Yes you would need to install koalas on all the nodes of the cluster. Typically all 3rd party libraries need to be installed on all the nodes of the cluster.